# TYPO3 Fluid dynamic key in arguments

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

I would like to render a partial with dynamic keys for the arguments.

In the partial:

```
<f:link.action action="{action}" controller="{controller}" 
arguments="{'{argument1name}': argument1, '{argument2name}': argument2}">
{bla}
</f:link.action>
```

So can argument1name and argument2name be written dynamicly in Fluid? What is the syntax, above is obviously wrong. Even better would be an array with an unknown number of arguments.

Comment: I must admit, I can not imagine a good reason for your usage of variable array key names. maybe you can evaluate the purpose  and maybe another solution can be found.

Comment: I am using it in a Bootstrap modal (popup window) and want to make the partial only once, for different actions, arguments etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution for my problem. In the Fluid Template..

```
<f:variable name="modalArguments" value="{organization: organization, contactperson: contactperson}"/>
<f:render partial="Components/ActionModal" arguments="{modalTitle: 'Bla', modalBody: 'Are you sure {contactperson.name} bla?', action: 'delete', controller: 'Contactperson', modalArguments: modalArguments}"/>
```

In the partial something like

```
<f:link.action action="{action}" controller="{controller}" arguments="{modalArguments}" class="btn btn-primary">bla</f:link.action>
```

So it's possible to throw the arguments array in a variable.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark the question as answered. This will help other people who are looking for answers or are trying to help people with unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

As in fluid the key for arrays never is wrapped in `'` your syntax obviously is wrong.
If a value is wrapped in `'` it is constant text, otherwise it is interpreted as variable. So keys are handled in another ways than values.